# Display all format files in Rails using send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-format

I have an application which has to display files of different formats. The list of formats maybe limited, but they consists of different formats. They can be .pdf, .docx, .odt, .png etc.

In my controller the show action looks like the following . The "content" is rendered from a given website which contains files of different formats.

```
    def show 
     send_data(content, :disposition => 'inline', :type => format_finder(params[:format]))
    end

    def format_finder(format)
        formats={"pdf" => "application/pdf",
       "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
       "png" => "image/png",
       "html" => "text/html",
       "odt" => "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
       "ods" => "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
       "jpg" => 'image/jpeg'}
     if formats.has_key?(format)
       return formats[format]
     end
   end
```

The problem is that the browser (chrome) is downloading the files instead of displaying them , except for PDF. How do I go about this issue ? Firefox is downloading all the files even if it is PDF.

Comment: AFAIK no browser has baked-in support to display odt / ods / docx.